# ios drag and drop view inside scrollview's subview

Tags: ios6, scrollview

Please help me,I am facing very critical situation,
with drag the view inside the scrollView's sub view.

**a:)** I have scrollview (**Let's Name A**) and inside this a view which cover whole scrollview(**Let's call B**), now **'B'** contains 225 subviews (15*15) (called **Target view**).

**b:)** I have another view just below of **A** with 7 subviews (called **tiles**) , each tiles reside inside a view (called **tileContaner View**).

Problem ?
1. When i drag the tile inside the **B**'s sub view (**Target view**) it's disappear .

Requirement .
place the **tile view** from tile container to scrollview's **target view** , or **B**'s sub view where Tile intersect Target.

Comment: in part c you have,                       tileView.frame=CGRectMake(targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20); I would think that because your doing targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y that it is just putting it off the screen. I would think its should be 0, 0 as your adding to view your getting your coordinates from.

Comment: @Boo: it's not working after adding the ileView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

Comment: then bringsubview to front and check for the rectintersection point of [A subviews] when it intersect any subview then add dragged view as subview of intersected view.

Comment: the above concept worked for me. but i am unable to put the dragged view when scrollview is scaled. would you like to help me if you already done that

Answer (score 0):

In this method remove  [tileView removeFromSuperview]; line because it actually remove tileView.

```
-(void)placeTile:(TileView*)tileView atTarget:(TargetView*)targetView {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.00 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i commented those line but still getting same issu

Answer (score 0):

// built from my comment

In part c you have, tileView.frame=CGRectMake(targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20); I would think that because your doing targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y that it is just putting it off the screen. I would think its should be 0, 0 as your adding to view your getting your coordinates from.

```
 -(void)placeTile:(TileView*)tileView atTarget:(TargetView*)targetView {
           [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.00 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

                 [tileView removeFromSuperview];
                 tileView.frame=CGRectMake(targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20);
                 [targetView addSubview:tileView];
                 NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",tileView.frame.origin.x,tileView.frame.origin.y,tileView.frame.size.width,tileView.frame.size.height);
                 [tileView bringSubviewToFront:targetView];

             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
            }];
```

See your setting the tileview to have the same x and y as targetView but the your adding to the target view. I would think you want to place it at 0,0 or maybe convert the point.

```
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.00 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
       animations:^{

             tileView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
             [targetView addSubview:tileView];
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
```

EDIT:

iMobile makes a good point the doc from apple say that addSubview removes the view if already has a super before adding it.

```
  "Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is
   not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the 
   receiver its new superview."
```

Comment: you remove   [tileView removeFromSuperview]; but you are not  reinitialize it so it may be nil check it please.

Comment: hmm unfortunate, on debug note maybe try targetView.clipsToBounds = NO; and have your tileView some bright colour.

Comment: @iOSRocks Also I would remove [tileView bringSubviewToFront:targetView];, looks to be wrong way around.

Comment: no not work..can you please give the idea to achieve this phenomenon .

Comment: i have same problem any body can help here .?